# Unexpected exception by DoCallBack() of AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

The following Code is running within my Setup application actually. But, if I call it from a unit test project, *tmpDom.DoCallBack(theCallback);* causes an exception. I stripped the code already down to a 'do nothing' Skeleton, but no change anyway!

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Setup
{
   internal class BMRegAsm
   {
      public bool RegisterDll()
      {
         AppDomain tmpDom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("DOMAIN-XYZ");
         string theName= tmpDom.FriendlyName; // Returns the correct name!
         try
         {
            CrossAppDomainDelegate theCallback = new CrossAppDomainDelegate(BMRegAsm.RegX);
            tmpDom.DoCallBack(theCallback);
         }
         catch (Exception exc)
         {
             Trace.WriteLine("==RegisterDll== " + exc.Message);
         }
      }

      private static void RegX() // Due to "static"-callback, no frmMain objects available.
      {
      }
   }
}
```

The following exception is thrown by *tmpDom.DoCallBack(theCallback);*

```
==RegisterDll== Die Datei oder Assembly "Setup, Version=4.14.4.199, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

Sorry for the German text. That means, the system cannot find the file specified.

Even I have the CallStack, I cannot evaluate what´s wrong.
*tmpDom.FriendlyName* returns the correct name.

Does anybody have an idea what causes the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the test project to see what is the output folder of the test build. Compare these list of files to the files under the "Setup application" output folder and see what file is missing.

To add a missing file there a few ways, depends on the file. For example:

- Set "Copy Local" to true for a reference file.
- Add copy commands to the post build event

Comment: The output directories of both projects are identical. I´m surprised that a file is missing, anyway, because the code does not use any file!?

Comment: What is the name of the missing file? are you running the test and the Setup application on the same machine?

Comment: No Name is mentioned. The fllowing shows the stack, last line: ´  mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName fileName, string codeBase, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly locationHint, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) Unknown´

Comment: are you running the test and the Setup application on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, same machine.

Comment: Do Test project and Setup application have the same target framework version? what about 32\64 bit?

Comment: Yes, both .net 4.0 and target x86.

Comment: I see that the missing file name is "Setup" with version Version=4.14.4.199. Do you have this DLL in both output folders?

Comment: Setup & Test Project uses the same output folder. The setup is a winForm exe program, whos method RegisterDll() should be tested by the test project. The code listed above is part of the setup.exe. So why and how can setup be missed? The code listed is very simple and doesn´t need any file. The only thing I can imagine is a wrong .Net reference, which causes the DoCallBack() to except. But how can I find out? I´m not familiar with the .Net internals. As I already mention, the used frameworks are both 4.0.

Comment: Can you post the exact code? I see the the RegisterDll does not return bool although it is according its signature.

Comment: Also can you change the internal to public? The access modifier of BMRegAsm

Comment: It is the current Code. I just forgot  AppDomain.Unload(tmpDom); and return bResult; with copy & paste, at the end of RegisterDll(). But I think the Environment causes the exception and not the Code itself.

Comment: ok, How can you use BMRegAsm in other project if its internal?

Comment: Just add `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Setup_Test")]` to the AssemblyInfo.cs file of your test candidate and make it so a friend to the UnitTest. Otherwise it would not compile.

Comment: Meanwhile I figured out what causes the exception. It´s a security issue. The [UnitTest] Attribute makes the UnitTest to _Partially_ _Trusted_ _Code_. Therefore the AppDomain does not allow access by methods of such Code. To handle this issue I must re- write the test applicants code, that it decreases the security level i.e. grant acces to non trusted code. There are a few examples on StackOverflow..